# Parse JSON with jQuery giving individual characters instead of entry values

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an AJAX callback which is supposed to return an entry value for each row in an array

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    datatype: JSON,
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            alert(key + ': ' + value);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error loading your request.  <br />Please try again later.');
    }
});
```

Instead of doing an `alert()` for each entry, it's doing an `alert()` for everything single character in the array.  It's as if it's drilling down one dimension too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your date is not being converted into json, it's looping over the characters in the response string.  Verify that data is what you think it is.

I suspect `datatype` needs to be `dataType`, and the value for that parameter needs to be "json"

Comment: Fixed it.  I don't know who down voted you, but that was the answer.